# Why Facelet HTML Validator validate my xhtml file don't complete

Tags: eclipse, facelets, validation

I have 1 file xthml as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
.......
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

After restart my eclipse 3.7, Eclipse perform validation but it always run :
"Facelet HTML validator starting to validate: student.xhtml".
If I disable Facelet validation in Windows - Preference, when I perform Ctrl + Space in this xhtml file, eclipse will be not responding. What do I have to do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Why is this file saved as `.xhtml` if it has no root `html` element?

Comment: @Hawken: because it's not a HTML file but a XHTML file.